# Ordering flow in asynchronous logic with long-ish callbacks

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The basic flow of this program is to receive UDP packets, look up some info on them, then send them off for further processing. The info is currently stored in mongodb.

Pseudo-JS is something like:

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    mongo.lookup(message, function(err, object) {
        furtherProcessing(object);
    });
});
```

I'm noticing odd/annoying behavior in this flow.

Since the mongodb is asynchronous, I observe that program flow switches to the next packet while waiting for the lookup to respond. This means that, if many packets arrive, we might have multiple mongodb requests interleaved (i.e. the program is awaiting a callback for multiple packets). Unfortunately, responses from mongo seem to be in random order (or perhaps order that they are satisfied by mongo), which means, by the time objects are passed to the `furtherProcessing` function, they may be reordered.

Is there any way to enforce FIFO ordering on async requests? That is, a way for me to guarantee that every object sent to `futherProcessing` is in the same order as it was received from the socket?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to code up the logic yourself with some sort of queue array.

You simply save the messages in the order they come in, and whenever any of the async tasks complete, you flag that one as complete and send everything at the front the queue that is complete to further processing.

This way if message 2, 3, 4 complete, it won't be sent until message 1 completes. Then all 4 would fly in the same runloop.

```
// outer queue to save messages
var queue = [];

socket.on('message', function(message) {

  // packet comes in, add it to the queue
  queue.push(message);

  // start the async lookup
  mongo.lookup(message, function(err, object) {

    // mark message compelte
    message.complete = true;

    // loop through the queue
    for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {

      // is the message task completed?
      if (queue[i].complete) {

        // further process this item
        furtherProcessing(queue[i]);


      // Found the first incomplete message!
      } else {

        // remove processed items so far from the queue
        // by making a new array from this index onward
        queue = queue.slice(i);

        // stop the loop
        return;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Khp3V/

The async lookup in this example will randomly take between 0ms and 500ms, which ensures out of order-ness.  But if you look at the console, it will list them in order as they are processed.